# Getting SubStrings after a character of varying lengths

Tags: php, string, substring

I'm trying to write a code that allows me to take specific characters after a string. Two examples of this string would be:

> End Table Brand New $50 
>   26"x18"x18" 
>   Needs Assembly. 
>   Black. 
>   I have a small warehouse of furniture 
>   To see the other items I have for sale type 2786741 in CL search bar or 
>   Hit the "more ads by this user" button 
>   Call or text 
>   show contact info

Example 2:

> Rocker Chair Brand New $185 
>       30"x36"x37". 
>       I have a small warehouse of furniture 
>       To see other items I have type 2786741 in CL search bar or 
>       Hit the "more ads by this user" button 
>       Call or Text show 
>       show contact info

Now what I'd like to do is pull just the price number and set it as its own separate string. I can't use something like `substr($data, strpos($description, "$") + 2);` because the length of the price varies. So I'm kind of at a loss. Any help would of course be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the php `preg_match` function to get the price. Example:

```
$str = 'End Table Brand New $50 26"x18"x18" Needs Assembly. Black. I have a small warehouse of furniture To see the other items I have for sale type 2786741 in CL search bar or Hit the "more ads by this user" button Call or text show contact info';
if (preg_match('/\$([\d,.]+)/', $str, $matches)) {
    $price = $matches[1];
    echo $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($data,strpos($description," ",strpos($description,"$")) - strpos($description,"$"))
```

this should find the strpos of the first space after the dollar sign and subtract the strpos of the dollar sign; you may have to add or subtract 1 to get it all lined up correctly